# How could I can assign roles to my user? My code it seems is not working. Do I am missing something?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building an ASP.NET MVC project. It is starting fine I have access to my regular pages, but I don't have access to my Administration web page.

I have tables for `ApplicationRole` and `ApplicationUser` and enums for the types of the roles for users.

ApplicationRole

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole, IAuditInfo, IDeletableEntity
{
        public ApplicationRole()
            : this(null)
        {
        }

        public ApplicationRole(string name)
            : base(name)
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IAuditInfo, IDeletableEntity
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.Roles = new HashSet<IdentityUserRole<string>>();
        this.Claims = new HashSet<IdentityUserClaim<string>>();
        this.Logins = new HashSet<IdentityUserLogin<string>>();
    }

    //[Required]
    //public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // Audit info
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    // Deletable entity
    [Required]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }

    public ICollection<IdentityUserRole<string>> Roles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<string>> Claims { get; set; }

    public ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<string>> Logins { get; set; }
}
```

My enum:

```
public enum UserRole
{
    Administrator = 0,
    Manager = 1,
    RegularUser = 2,
}
```

In the `UserController` that is located in Area -> Administration, it is responsible for assigning and creating roles.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Roles(UserRolesViewModel model)
{
        var user = await userService.GetUserById(model.UserId);
        var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        await userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, userRoles);

        if (model.RoleNames?.Length > 0)
        {
            await userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, userRoles);
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(ManageUsers));
}
```

Create role:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole()
{
    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole()
        {
            Name = "ArtGallery"
        });

    return Ok();
}
```

I can register 1 user and log in but when I log in am have access only to my regular page. I don't see my Administration pages in the Browser but they are in the app. I don't know if I am missing something or if something is wrong because my user currently doesn't have any role.

Could somebody help me to resolve this issue, please?

Comment: I might be missing it, but where are you actually adding the role to the user?

Comment: can you go to the admin pages directly, via url? Is it a problem in how you are building up your views? There's so many steps between what you have shared here and how you have described the problem that it's difficult to deduce. Have you put breakpoints and ensured that roles are being assigned to users?

Comment: To @flashplat: I am not quite sure but await userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, userRoles); shouldn't add role too the use.

Comment: I did not try using URLs but I have Dashboard Navigation for the Administration web page but it is not accessible because it is in the same location Area -> Administration -> View

Comment: I think you probably need to remove the `Roles` property from your `ApplicationUser`, since it's already on the `IdentityUser`?

Comment: @StanislavaStoeva  It looks like your getting the roles the user currently has (which would be none) and then ... well basically I don't think it's ever getting into your IF, and if it does, it's applying roles that don't exist.  Check out the little sample I put below.

Comment: @flashsplat I know I am creating a user without a role. It just when I am creating my user my roles doesn’t creates with my user but I have a code for creating roles. I am not completely sure what cause this issue. I suspect as my extended table user Id is in my joined aspnetUsersRoles table could cause this issue with my role, but not sure if this is the case.

Comment: @StanislavaStoeva As I understand your code, if a user has no roles, it will never enter your IF statement , and will never get assigned a role.  Try assigning a role without the if to see if that resolves your problem, then go back and take a look at your logic again.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the role manager to find the role first, then assign it to the user.  Something like this:

```
public class YOURCLASS : Controller
{
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly UserManager<TMSUser> _userManager;

    public YOURCLASS( RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<TMSUser> userManager )
    {
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> YOURACTION()
    {
        var user = CreateUser();
        var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("ArtGallery");

        if (role != null && !(await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name)))
        {
            var addRoleResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
        }
    }
    
}
```